# Subtract a specific row from a csv using phyton

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two csv files: one containing data, the other one containing a single row with the same columns as the first file. I am trying to subtract the one row from the second file from all the rows from the first file using pandas.

I have tried the following, but to no avail.

```py
df = df.subtract(row, axis=1)
```

Comment: Try 'row.values' (the order of the columns should be strictly the same)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "drop" method. From pandas docs:

df
A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11

drop by index:

df.drop([0, 1])
A  B   C   D
2  8  9  10  11

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html